# Looping two arrays of different type items (string and image) with ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, string, image, loops, swiftui

In stead to have an array of image under an array of text, I would like to have one array alternatively with image or text depending if I push the button text or the button picture.

Here is what I have tried:

```
struct HistoryPicture: Identifiable {let id = UUID ()
var picture: Image?}

struct HistoryText: Identifiable {let id = UUID ()
    var text: String?}

struct ContentView: View {

@State var archivePicture: [HistoryPicture] = []
@State var archiveText: [HistoryText] = []

var body: some View {ScrollView{

        VStack(spacing:20){
            
                ForEach(self.archiveText) { item in
                        Text("<text>")
                        }

                ForEach(self.archivePicture) { item in
                    Image("simpson")
                        }
      // Button Text

            HStack{

                Button {var newHistory = HistoryText()
                    newHistory.text = "<text>"
                   self.archiveText.append(newHistory)

                } label: { Circle()
                             .fill(Color.black)
                             .frame(width: 70, height: 70)} }

    // Button Picture

            HStack{

                Button {var newHistoryPicture = HistoryPicture()
                        newHistoryPicture.picture =     Image("simpson")
                        self.archivePicture.append(newHistoryPicture)

                    } label: { Circle()
                                 .fill(Color.red)
                                 .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    }} }} }}
```

Comment: you should have an array of `Dictionary` here and your model should be like:    `struct History: Identifiable {   let id = UUID()   var text : String?    var image :  Image?}`, check this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary)

Comment: Thank you! Would you initialise an empty array of Dictionary like this   @State var archive: [[String : Image]] = [[:]]

Comment: Then iterating over the contents of a dictionary with for as mentioned in the documentation link     for (text,image) in archive {

                    if archive.text != nil {
                        Text("<text>")}
                    else if archive.image != nil {
                        Image("simpson")
                    }
                }

Comment: make me an error as Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with result builder: "ViewBuilder"

Comment: I have tried to use ForEach like this                 ''' ForEach(self.$archive.text.image) { item in
                    if (item.text != nil)  {
                        Text("<text>")}
                    else if (item.image != nil)  {
                        Image("simpson")}
                    } '''

Comment: I have another message error “Value of type ‘Binding<[[String : Image]] has no dynamic member ‘text’ using key path from root type ‘[[String : Image]]’

Comment: Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this solution you get the results in the order the buttons were pressed. For that you just need one ForEach with one struct. If you want more complex views inside the ForEach, I would suggest using Protocols or inheritance.

```swift
struct HistoryItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text: String?
    var imageName: String?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var items = [HistoryItem]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20){
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    if let text = item.text {
                        Text(text)
                    } else if let imageName = item.imageName {
                        Image(imageName)
                    }
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Button {
                        let newItem = HistoryItem(text: "<text>")
                        items.append(newItem)
                    } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.black)
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    }
                    
                    Button {
                        let newItem = HistoryItem(imageName: "simpson")
                        items.append(newItem)
                    } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color.red)
                            .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Great! But, the project is little bit different. Initially inside my code I have String and Image type (because I am importing images from the camera). That's why I was trying to use ForEach with two array or with an array of dictionary. What would happen inside the code above if ''' var imageName: Image?''' instead of '''var imageName: String? '''?

Comment: Sure, it works the same way, you can use var image: Image? and in the ForEach if let image = item.image { image }

Comment: Thank you Gregor! Yes it functions! The solution is to use only one array just because Image is at the end a String; and array admits always one same type of elements. Is it correct?

Comment: You’re right about arrays, but it’s because the elements are all HistoryItems. Images are not Strings; they’re a separate type. The image is a field of HistoryItem and it’s type does not matter to the array.